# WebView vs. Chrome - very different

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, android-websettings

I am making an Android application using a webview for a part of the screen. The problem I am facing is that the webview is not displaying the webpage correctly.

Website: String webview_url = http://marci539.getmarci.com/?c=custom_skin_1

It displays fine on the Chrome browser but when I try to display it in the webiew, that's where the problem is.

Has anyone ever faced a similar issue? How did you manage to solve it?
This is my webview code:

```
    wvWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvWeb);
    wvWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    wvWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    wvWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    wvWeb.loadUrl(webview_url);
    wvWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```